# How do I edit a label's text after creating them?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt4

I want to edit a label's text after creating it, yet it's giving me an error. What exactly did I do wrong?

```
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 500, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle("PyQt test!")

        QtGui.QApplication.setStyle(QtGui.QStyleFactory.create("plastique"))

        self.home()
    def home(self):
        btn = QtGui.QPushButton("New game", self)
        btn.clicked.connect(self.change)
        btn.resize(300,25)
        btn.move(100, 175)
        txt = "Welcome to the main menu! (WIP obviously)"

        lbl = QtGui.QLabel(txt, self)
        lbl.resize(400, 100)
        lbl.move(50, 25)
        lbl.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.show()
    def change(self, txt):
        txt = "test"
        self.lbl.setText(txt)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\Home\Desktop\So it begins (PyQt).py", line 47, in change
>       self.lbl.setText(txt)
>   AttributeError: 'Window' object has no attribute 'lbl'

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you called `home()` and created `lbl` first?

Comment: Edited the question... I really have no idea where the problem originates from. When I ask a question here I usually end up posting too much unnecessary code or too little code. Being a newbie isn't fun...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not declaring `lbl` as a property. Because of this, it is out of scope once your code leaves the `home()` method and there is no way to get a reference to the object.

Append `self.lbl = lbl` to your `home()` method as so:

```
lbl = QtGui.QLabel(txt, self)
lbl.resize(400, 100)
lbl.move(50, 25)
lbl.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
self.lbl = lbl
```

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to just use `self.lbl` for each operation? instead of using `lbl` and then `self.lbl`?

Comment: personally I don't think it's as clean. Not so bad with a short variable name, but I'm not a fan of constant property access.